# How does jQuery's .not() return value affect .hide()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple HTML table and jQuery set up to hide the rows when user clicks a desired topic so only the clicked one remains visible.
My question is, although the script is working I'm not sure why and going through jQuery documentation didn't really help me understand this.

Here's the simple logic behind the topic removal process:

```
if (topic != 'All') {
    $('#news').find('tr:has(td)').not(function() {
        return $(this).children(':nth-child(4)').text() == topic;
    }).hide();
}
```

When the .not() method returns TRUE, the topic is excluded from removal and when it returns FALSE the topic is effectively removed. Why is that? What is the relation between the return value of .not() and .hide()? How does the return value of .not() affect the execution of .hide()?

Comment: Huh? The `not` function is a jQuery method, and like most jQuery methods it can be chained. `not` removes the elements that match the condition in the callback, and returns the rest of the elements to the collection to be chained, and in that regard it's just like `find`, which you're also using! What's not to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find` method will find the elements matching its selector, then the `not` method will run the callback function for each of those elements. Each element where the callback function returns `true` will be removed from the set of elements that is returned by the `not` method.

The `hide` method will hide the elements that remain in the set.

The code could be written like this to show the separate steps:

```
if (topic != 'All') {

  var allRows = $('#news').find('tr:has(td)');

  var allRowsExceptTopic = allRows.not(function() {
    return $(this).children(':nth-child(4)').text() == topic;
  });

  allRowsExceptTopic.hide();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation for .not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/0):

> Description: Remove elements from the set of matched elements.

So to break down the jQuery object construction, here's what's happening:

1. `$('#news')` = Select the element identified by `news`
2. `find('tr:has(td)')` = Select that elements' children who are `tr`s that contain `td`s.
3. `.not(` = Remove the elements from the collection (already established!) that match the selector or set of objects passed to this method. See the documentation for what is acceptable as the parameters to `.not`. One is `function` which tests each element in the existing set, and returns a `true` or `false` to determine removal or not.
4. `function() {
       return $(this).children(':nth-child(4)').text() == topic;
   }` = Test the element (iterates over each in the collection) and return true (an item to be removed!) if the elements' text matches the topic in question. Note that this is only removing the element in question from the set. All the rest are left alone.
5. `.hide()` = Hide everything that has been left in the collection.

For what it's worth, this is conceptually difficult to understand, since it uses reverse tests to decide things.

Remember that in step 4, it's returning `false` for every element that doesn't match the right text, which triggers `.not()` to remove only the matching element from the set.